# web.config rewrite from one directory to another

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I'm struggling to transform an Apache .htaccess rewrite to an IIS rewrite. I would like to rewrite from one directory to another.

Example: If someone accesses the URI: `/booklets/MyPDF.pdf` then the rewrite would access the file using `/res/pdf/MyPDF.pdf`

This is what I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite for booklets location" enabled="true">
            <match url="^booklets/(.*).pdf" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="res/pdf/{R:1}.pdf" />
        </rule>

      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to your own answer i would suggest you to add `stopProcessing` attribute and backslash dot symbol before extension in regular expression:

```
   <rule name="Rewrite for booklets location" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^booklets/(.*)\.pdf$" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="res/pdf/{R:1}.pdf"/>
   </rule>
```

Comment: if i want to redirect from /booklets/a.pdf to .res/booklets/a.pdf keeping same folder name i giving problem any suggestion

Answer (score 3):

After tinkering around with it, I just removed `enabled="true"` from the rule and added the ending regex `$` to the url match, and now it works!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite for booklets location">
            <match url="^booklets/(.*).pdf$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="res/pdf/{R:1}.pdf" />
        </rule>

      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```